# Using a template within a template - eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

As I slowly crawl in my transition from .net to Java, I find more and more interesting things about the eclipse IDE. I recently stumbled upon its templates and I'm loving it. Which brings me to a question: can I call a template from within a template? Of course it would be merely a copy and paste matter, but I'm wondering if it can be done.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? Eclipse doesn't have mechanism to expand template inside another template, but you can copy & paste if you need to.

Comment: @Pakka, I'm looking at the default "New Java Files" template and it uses four unique sub-templates.  It's not really that big a deal.  Just make sure that your set of templates forms a directed acyclic graph and you won't have recursive template problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, actually, you can and there is an example right in the default set.

If you go to your Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates, you can **Export All** of the provided Java templates.  In there you will see the following *File* template (formatted for readability):

```
<template 
    autoinsert="true" 
    context="filecomment_context" 
    deleted="false" 
    description="Comment for created Java files" 
    enabled="true" 
    id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.codetemplates.filecomment" 
    name="filecomment">
    /** * */
</template>
```

and a bit further down, the *New Type* which makes use of that *File* template:

```
<template 
    autoinsert="true" 
    context="newtype_context" 
    deleted="false" 
    description="Newly created files" 
    enabled="true" 
    id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.codetemplates.newtype" 
    name="newtype">
    ${filecomment} ${package_declaration} ${typecomment} ${type_declaration}
</template>
```

So, if you'd like to make a template use another, the basic form is to refer to the id of your sub-template with the dollar sign prefix.  For example:

```
<template 
    autoinsert="true" 
    context="BobOuter_context" 
    deleted="false" 
    description="Bob example outer template" 
    enabled="true" 
    id="bob.example.outertemplate" 
    name="BobOuter">
    BobOuterBegins Insert inner template ${bob.example.innertemplate} BobOuterEnds
</template> 

<template 
    autoinsert="true" 
    context="BobInner_context" 
    deleted="false" 
    description="Bob example inner template" 
    enabled="true" 
    id="bob.example.innertemplate" 
    name="BobInner">
    BobInnerBegins Super awesome content goes here BobInnerEnds
</template>
```

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish this directly in the built-in template editor?