# Can an Eclipse Editor Template invoke another template

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-jdt, eclipse-templates

I saw in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6898575/633267) that an Eclipse *Code Template* can invoke another template by editing the exported xml. I tried this with an Eclipse *Editor Template* but it didn't work. I added an id element to template A and referenced that id in template B but it didn't work. I'm wondering if it's possible to get this capability in an *Editor Template*.